# Default ASP.NET core project failing to publish

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am making my first .net core app.  I just created the default asp.net core web app inside visual studio template and then tried `dotnet publish` but I get this error:

```
PM> dotnet publish
dotnet : 'D:\Projects\coreTest\CoreTest' does not contain a project.json file
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet publish
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ('D:\Projects\co...oject.json file:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I haven't changed anything.  The default template includes a `project.json` file with dependencies listed.  Why doesn't it want to publish?

Comment: Can you verify that the `project.json` file exists and is valid?

Comment: It exists.  Visual studio created it and filled in dependencies when I created the default web app project.  The path is `D:\Projects\coreTest\CoreTest\src\CoreTest` so I think its looking in wrong path when im running this in package manager console.

Comment: Does `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` work on that exact folder?

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli `dotnet restore` works fine on the projects.json file in nested folder but both `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` complain there is no projects.json file as it is looking one level up.  I am able to build project from menu and also preview it fine by hitting play.  It's just these commands in package manager console seem to be looking in wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug with package manager.  I managed to publish the project by right clicking the project and selecting publish.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone running into this and ending up on this answer, it is possible that you have a mismatch between `dotnet --version` on different machines where you are trying to compile.

There is a [breaking change](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/) in transitioning from `project.json` back to MS Build.

I was trying to compile an app built for the MS Build version on an environment with the `project.json` version and ran into this. As a noob when it comes to new .NET stuff, and having not followed the changes too closely, I didn't realize this was the culprit for some time.