# .NET Core 1.1 vs preview3 for Azure deploy

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm kind of lost in versions. Do we have to download

Preview 3 : https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/preview3-download.md

or current 1.1 SDK: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current

for our app to be deployed into Azure properly. As I can see from **Azure Console** in a web app:

```
dotnet --version
D:\home\site\wwwroot
1.0.0-preview3-004056
```

I tried to push (via git deploy) a 1.0 preview 2 app into Azure, but it failed:

> D:\home\site\repository\App.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: The imported
>   project "D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview3-004056\Extensions\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Is there any change to make to my code?

If i set a Global.json file containing my current dotnet version:

```
{
    "projects": [],
    "sdk": { "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131" }
}
```

Then i get an error of another kind.

```
'App.xproj' does not contain a project.json file
remote: Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "App.xproj" --output "D:\local\Temp\8d42b497bccf2b0" --configuration Release
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

So, **what is the proper versions of tools and code to use to deploy properly on Azure?**

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingASPNETCore11ApplicationsToAzureUsingGitDeploy.aspx

Comment: I read and tried to reproduce what's mentionned in this blog. But as you can see, even with the global json, i get an error.

Comment: why you have 1.0.0-preview3-004056, but in Global.json 1.0.0-preview2-003131?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757609/net-core-1-1-0-visual-studio-tooling

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625085/default-asp-net-core-project-failing-to-publish

Comment: i don't have preview3. Preview3 is the output of **Azure** console. So it seems they updated build tools on Azure apps?

Comment: maybe you should update it too?